# How can I configure Jinja2 to automatically format and indent the rendered HTML and also validate it for HTML5 conformance?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

How can I configure Jinja2 to automatically format and indent the rendered HTML and also validate it for HTML5 conformance? I've looked at lxml and html5lib, but I'm not sure about how to implement them myself.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a task of a template engine.

What you can do is that you can run Jinja generated HTML through validator, tidy, etc. as a post processing task for your website. Usually this is done [using WSGI middleware](http://rufuspollock.org/2006/09/28/wsgi-middleware/).

Example of writing a simple WSGI middeware with Flask: http://eddmann.com/posts/creating-a-basic-auth-wsgi-middleware-in-python/

Your middleware would

- Inspect outgoing HTTP response
- If it's text/html content type
- Parse HTML, run it through validator, do something with validation errors, rewrite the outgoing HTML with wanted indentation options

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding the right mix of python modules that can parse the HTML5 and format it for me.

Comment: @Corey: I suggest you split your problem to subproblems and open a new question for "How to format HTML5 with Python"